# Classification Residual Analysis with rank-based goal

Tags: residuals, ranking, ranks

I have a dataset consisting of users, each with a number of items (ranging from 1 to 100). The end-goal is for each user to be able to predict the ranking the of the items according to some other measure of popularity.

Let's assume I have train an algorithm to do this and can compare my results to the actual rankings. Now I would like to analyze where my rankings are most different compared to the ground truth. What sort of methods exist to analyze this sort of residual? (that is a measure of the quality of a given ranking)